# Windows keyboard shortcut for deselecting text?

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts, selection

Is there a keyboard shortcut for deselecting selected text? Perhaps it also works for deselecting selected items (in Windows Explorer)?

The arrow keys work in some software, but sometimes they also move the text cursor one character left/right. This latter behavior happens when selecting text in Windows Explorer for example.

I would like to have a global shortcut with consistent behavior. Don't bother with AutoHotKey tomfoolery, though. If it isn't built in, then that's just the way it is! (A registry tweak to enable it would be OK, just no external software please.)

Comment: I don't know if there is a solution for this. I use a ton of shortcuts. F10 pulls focus off?

Comment: That's a useful one I didn't know! But it doesn't quite accomplish the intended operation.

Comment: I was sure it didn't solve your problem or else I would have posted it as a solution. I'm not sure if there is a shortcut that exists for that. I think you will have to invent something or write a program. A way to deselect text is to just click anywhere else on the screen, that works too. I mean, even F5 refreshes the browser. Selecting text is done with a mouse isn't it? Just click off to the side somewhere.

Comment: @Juiced: Text editing apps: yes, but also browsers, for example. I don't understand what you mean with, "and then select the text, etc.". Select how, exactly? What keys should I use to (de)select the text, etc.?

Comment: I think what Juice is talking about is the SHIFT key. If you, a person, click on some text and wish to deselect the text, or back your way out of it, hold the SHIFT key and LEFT-ARROW your way out of it. That's all I got. Good luck.

Comment: How is "clicking" a keyboard shortcut, though?

Comment: Clicking is not a keyboard shortcut but I wasn't sure if you were looking for a way to get it done quickly regardless if it's a windows shortcut or not so that's why I put all that in a comment rather than an answer to clarify and so on. Good luck!